# Android - Call an Asynctask from an Asynctask with infinity loop

Tags: android, android-asynctask, infinite-loop

I have 2 Asynctask, 1 for get data (location) from server then set a marker on map with this location and another call 1st Asyntask in a loop for updating location.
Here my code:

```
public class AsynComp extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    ProgressDialog taxiDialog;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        jsonComp = new JSONComp(find_url);
        find_status = jsonComp.getJsonStatus(txt_search);
        return null;
    } 

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (find_status.equals("2013")) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "no result",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else if (find_status.equals("2012")) {
            for (Marker marker:markers){
                if(marker.getTitle().equals(compFollow)){
                    marker.remove();
                }
            }
            for (int i=0; i<number;i++){
                comp = new Comp(jsonComp.getJsondata(i));
                SetMarkerComp(comp);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1400);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}

public class AsynFollow extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        if (!taxiFollow.equals("")) {
            number = 1;
            txt_search = compFollow;
            find_url = "http://192.111.125.80:8001/Default.aspx?username=" 
                        + Id + "&password=" + Pass + "&sohieuxe="+txt_search;
            while (!stop){
                new AsynComp().execute();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            taxiFollow = "";
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (!compFollow.equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Follow "+compFollow, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            iv_theodoi.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            iv_theodoif.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Plz choose a marker", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }   
}
```

And i have 2 buuton, 1 to call AsynFollow.execute(), another to stop it.
This code can run but app will force close after awhile.
Any solution? thanks.
P/s: i'm a newbie in android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoulnd you asyncTask for this. For repetitive action, like changing status in some interval, use [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) class. In this way you can implement repetitive action which can be repeated in intervals.

In this way you can stop this time by on click listener. You can run two times and specify it's realtions using other variables.

If you're newbe, you should read about multitasking in Android: [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html), [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

In my opinion this docs will tell you much more than thousands of comments in stackoverflow.